# Docker - How to get the name (user/repo:tag) of the base image used to build another image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I run `docker history mysql` the last line is:

```
104de4492b99  9 days ago  /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:f35a56605b9a065a14 4.97 MB
```

I wanted to know what base image the id `f35a56605b9a065a14` corresponds to, so I found the mysql Dockerfile on Github. The first line is:

```
FROM debian:wheezy
```

1) Can someone confirm that `f35a56605b9a065a14` is indeed the id of the `debian:wheezy` base image?

2) If I didn't have access to the Dockerfile, how would I go about making the connection that `f35a56605b9a065a14` corresponds to `debian:wheezy`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you just have an image and want to recreate the Dockerfile, you can use 
dockerfile-from-image from

https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image/blob/master/dockerfile-from-image.rb

it is some Ruby code (in a container, of course!) that find all the commands used.

And, yes f35... is the id of DEBIAN:WHEEZY, as

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock   centurylink/dockerfile-from-image debian:wheezy`

shows

`ADD file:f35a56605b9a065a14a18d0e36fdf55c1c381d3521b4fa7f11173f0025d36839 in /
CMD ["/bin/bash"]`
`

Comment: That answers my 1st question but not the 2nd: If we didn't have access to the dockerfile, how would we end up knowing that f35... corresponds to debian:wheezy

Comment: I messed up in my answer and forgot to add it, but `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock centurylink/dockerfile-from-image mysql`  shows (among other things) `FROM debian:wheezy` you can check it

Comment: Awesome! do you have any idea how it gets that information? Also, would you know why the output of dockerfile-from-image is different for mysql (dockerfile output) and debian:wheezy (docker history output).

Comment: if you look at the code, it is in this part `# Collect all image tags into a hash keyed by layer ID.
# Used to look-up potential FROM targets.
tags = Docker::Image.all.each_with_object({}) do |image, hsh|
tag = image.info['RepoTags'].first
hsh[image.id] = tag unless tag == NONE_TAG`    see the doc of dockerfile-from-image https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image

Comment: Turns out the method you mentioned only works if the debian:wheezy image has already been *explicitely* pulled (using the `docker pull` or `docker run` commands). I had to undo accepted answer. I would upvote if I could.